# What's the difference between assigning an array to a temp array normally vs making a new array and then assigning it?

Tags: java, arraylist, subset

I was trying to solve a leetcode question (ques 78), and the logic was pretty clear to me but for some reason, I could never implement it.

```
    class Solution {
    public List<List<Integer>> subsets(int[] nums) {
        
        
ArrayList<List<Integer>> arr = new ArrayList();

arr.add(new ArrayList<>());

for (int i = 0; i<nums.length; i++) {
    
    int n = arr.size();
    
    for (int j = 0; j<n; j++) {
        
        List<Integer> temp = new ArrayList(arr.get(j)) ;
        
        temp.add(nums[i]);
        
        arr.add(temp);
        
    }
    
    
}

return arr; 
   
    }
}
```

The above code works perfectly (as I'm creating a new ArrayList before copying the arr.get(j) array) but the code below doesn't

```
    class Solution {
    public List<List<Integer>> subsets(int[] nums) {
        
        
ArrayList<List<Integer>> arr = new ArrayList();

arr.add(new ArrayList<>());

for (int i = 0; i<nums.length; i++) {
    
    int n = arr.size();
    
    for (int j = 0; j<n; j++) {
        
        List<Integer> temp = arr.get(j) ;
        
        temp.add(nums[i]);
        
        arr.add(temp);
        
    }
    
    
}

return arr; 
   
    }
}
```

Sorry, if I sound frustrated but, Why! on the rooftop of the world is the second code producing a weird result? What's the difference? I wasted hours on this.

Comment: are you asking why we need " new ArrayList(arr.get(j)) ;" or are you asking that you cant find the difference between the two codes?

Comment: The first condition sir, I get the difference, I just wanna know why

Comment: Poor title. Rewrite to summarize your specific technical issue.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first one, is creating **shallow copy** of `arr.get(j)` into `temp`.

The second solution just copy the value of `arr.get(j)` (which is a reference) to `temp`. They will both refer to the same object.

Comment: Thanks, got it now